# Forcing response headers

Tags: web-application, php, http, file-upload

I'm testing a particular vulnerability box since yesterday and I came with one rather strange problem that I didn't expect. Lets say a vulnerable web-application offer image file upload.

The image actually doesn't have to be image, the back-end accept any file exstension. The problem is, same back-end always returns `*.jpg` so instead of uploaded `evil.php` script, you come up with `random_number.jpg`.

Of course, the first thing I've tried is getting the served response, which in this case is base64-encoded image data.

Looking further, I've found that the application returns `binary/octet-stream` as a **Content-type** response header which means when I try to access the URL `http://localhost/vulnbox/uploaded/random_num.jpg`, the browser opens file download message. The actual file is returned as binary, ready to be downloaded, yet looking into the file, I see that the code stays in.

Is there a way I can force response of Content-type to any other and get actual evil script ran?

Comment: You can set the `Accept` header to `text/html` as part of the content negotiation. Whether the server will actually reply differently depends on its configuration, though.

Comment: Additionally, some kinds of data retrieval requests let you specify a content type. This is usually done for data that can be represented in multiple ways - as JSON or XML, for example - and your web app may not even have a parameter like that anywhere, but it's worth looking for one. It'll usually be a URL query string parameter, something like `format=xml` or similar. If that works, you can probably XSS the site by uploading HTML and then requesting it with the parameter set to give it to you as XML.

Comment: Oooh, another possibility: Flash applets! Flashplayer has a number of questionable security decisions in it. Among these: an applet has privileged access to the site it was loaded from (it can make requests to that domain, with cookies, and see responses, without a `crossdomain.xml` or similar). Also, you can make Flashplayer ignore the Content-Type header of the server response, so long as the server doesn't also set `Content-Type-Options: nosniff` (maybe `X-` prefixed). Upload a malicious SWF, load another site with `<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="*uploadurl*" />`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to know if there is a way to execute the uploaded PHP file. **Short Answer:** No

**Long Anwser:**
As long as the web server is configured correctly only .php files gets executed as PHP. Most web servers will return as content type always the mime type derived from the file extension. The content itself of the HTTP response is typically the content of the file. For example Apache2 will return you the content type 'image/jpg' and the plain text of the PHP file.